# How to disable screen lock on my HTC desire Z?

Tags: htc-desire-z, lock-screens

I would like to disable screen lock completely, as anyway there is need to press power button every time + unlock the screen which is anyoing

Answer (score 7):

Try [No Lock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/no-lock/org.jraf.android.nolock).  Probably will do what you want.  Doesn't work on all phones.

Comment: You should probably accept his answer.