# How can I set a Screen Lock Timeout?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-tab, lock-screens, password

I'd like to have to enter the PIN not immediately after pressing the standby button, but only after some time, e.g. 30 minutes.

I know there is [Password Delay](http://willemstoker.nl/index.php/android/passworddelay), which is better than nothing. But it works only if you keep the application running and the application itself is not password-protected. **Update**: newer versions of Password Delay work okay (no more need to keep it running, application is now password-protected).

Are there better solutions? Or do technical limitations of Froyo prevent better solutions?

For Reference: [tested.com](http://www.tested.com/news/how-to-make-the-android-lock-screen-do-more-for-you/580/) (found via https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/780/what-is-a-good-lock-program-for-android-phones) mentions [Lock Delay](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.brandongoodman.smartlock) and [AutoLock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.mooapps.autolock), but these work only on 2.1 or below.

And [How to disable screen lock on my HTC desire Z?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4099/how-to-disable-screen-lock-on-my-htc-desire-z) proposes [No Lock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/no-lock/org.jraf.android.nolock), but this is a solution of a different problem (complete disable the lock, not just delay it).

Comment: The Lock Delay author mentions that Google has locked down the API relevant to locking in Froyo. Could be the reason why there aren't apps available.

Answer (score 4):

I have a HTC Desire running Froyo, and I can go to **Settings | Security | Lock phone after** and choose the timeout to "Immediately", 3, 5 10 or 15 minutes.

Doesn't the Galaxy Tab have this setting?

Comment: no, the Galaxy Tab has just **Set screen lock** in the section **Screen unlock setting**. A colleague with a HTC also showed me that his device has a setting more in this section.