# Looking for app that provides different screen timeout and lock timeout

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, lock-screens, screen-timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a Screen Lock Timeout?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4706/how-can-i-set-a-screen-lock-timeout)

I would like to extend the lock timeout for my phone so that it is about 10 to 20 minutes till a password/pattern/pin is needed.  However, I don't want the screen to stay on that long.  Is there an application that either allows different timeouts, or provides it's own timeout for the screen, so that I can set it to a time less than the native timeout?

I have Froyo (2.2) on a Samsung Captivate (or Galaxy S).

Comment: Note that (as per that question) phones like the HTC Desire apparently have the ability to set two different timeouts, but the Galaxy S does not.  Of course there might be an app workaround, but I don't know of one.

Comment: You really shouldn't be asking for an app; app recommendations are off-topic here. If you can rephrase your question to be about the problem you're having and ways to resolve it, your question can probably avoid being closed.

Comment: @Al, I can see your point.  However, I do see a qualitative difference between "hey, what's a good app for looking up restaurant ratings" vs. "is there an app that can do such and such?"  that being said, I suppose I can rephrase the question, but it will probably be deleted for being a duplicate.

Comment: @Matthew Read, with your link I see that this question is indeed probably a duplicate.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @Chance You don't need to delete it.  Now that the question is closed, it will remain here to help users search -- their search might pull up this question but not the other, so this will act to point them in the right direction.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks. I realized my mistake after I deleted it.