# how to completely disable lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable screen lock on my HTC desire Z?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4099/how-to-disable-screen-lock-on-my-htc-desire-z)

is there any way to do this ?
kinda unnecessary on android

Comment: I wouldn't say it's unnecessary.  Without the lock screen you could potentially "butt dial" if the screen came on for any reason

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4099/how-to-disable-screen-lock-on-my-htc-desire-z

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings --> Location & security settings --> Set up screen lock -->  None.

Note: this may be a CyanogenMod feature.  I can't remember if Stock Android allows this or not (can someone verify this for me?)

Comment: On my HTC Hero with regular Android 2.1 there is no such option; on Security I can only add/remove a screen unlock pattern, but nothing about the screen lock.

Comment: On my HTC Desire HD, with Android 2.2, the option is at Settings > **Security** > Set up screen lock > None

Answer (score 0):

Use the app called "no lock". It will allow you to toggle between having a lock screen and having none.